# Null. Reference. Exception: Object reference not set to an instance of an object "Unity3D"

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development, unity3d-2dtools

I'm new to Unity3D. I've chosen a project from a website to learn from and modifying as a starting point to become more familiar with how things work. The project opens without errors in console except this pop up message, but when I hit the play button, six errors pop up in the console. They all seem to be essentially the same error. I believe that if I can get some help solving one, I can work my way through the rest.

[image: Pop up message]
[image: Console]
[image: Inspector]
Script line

```
    private void Awake()
    {
        Intance = this;
        song = CoreData.instance.GetCurrentSong();
#if ENABLE_AMANOTES
        noteDatas = new List<NoteData>();
        string text = (!RemoteFilesData.instance.IsLocalSong(song.path)) ? RemoteFilesData.LocalPath(song.path) : song.path;
        text = text.Replace(".mp3", ".bin");
        byte[] array = RemoteFilesData.LoadFileBinary(text);
        if (array != null)
        {
            NoteGeneration.LoadFileContent(RemoteFilesData.LoadFileBinary(text), Difficulty.Easy, delegate(List<NoteData> resSucess)
            {
                noteDatas = resSucess;
            }, delegate(string errorLog)
            {
                Debug.LogError("Spawner.Awake error" + errorLog);

            });
        }
```

I would be thankful if any of you could assist me with this one.